# use select count(*) everytime or save the count as a number directly

Tags: sql, database, select, count

Today when creating a database I found to use select count(*) or save the count as a number are both available in this case.

So I'm wondering if there are some performance differences between them? How to choose?

Comment: I don't get it. Can you rephrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count(*) is most reliable becuase it gives correct count even when some rows are deleted from the table

Comment: Thanks, Madhivanan. But I'm sure the rows won't be deleted.